# Opening port with IP tables and UFW doesn't appear to open port

Tags: 16.04, server, iptables, firewall, ssl

I have attempted to open port 443 on a server I'm working on (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 433 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The port doesn't appear to be open:

```
nmap cubicverse.com

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-06-18 17:52 BST
Nmap scan report for cubicverse.com (104.131.17.139)
Host is up (0.15s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http
```

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 39.61 seconds
Product of iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:433 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I have also opened the port with ufw.

What alternative steps may be needed to open the port?

I am attempting to add an SSL cert for this server, and the 'SSL checker' keeps telling me I have a closed port and hence it can't validate the CSR.

I also know the port isn't open because:

[decoder.link/sslchecker/www.cubicverse.com/443](http://decoder.link/sslchecker/www.cubicverse.com/443)

Comment: Is this any more than a simple typo? you've opened **433** whereas the checker appears to require **443**

Comment: @Thomas no-one would have answered there. If there is a referencing criteria please tell me.

Comment: @steeldriver upvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open port with `iptables` command is

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

For `UFW`

```
sudo ufw allow 443
```

Experience has learn me that it not good to mix `iptables` and `ufw`. Use only one of them.